# tkinter: Can't make frame scrollable

Tags: python, tkinter

On python tkinter, I am using 2 different frames on a Toplevel window, one on the right and another on the left.
The frame which is on right side is not scrollable. I have created a canvas on top of the frame on that frame and one more frame on top of that canvas. I have made that canvas scrollable and pasted the widgets on that canvas but it's not scrollable. I am attaching the code of the scrollable part.

```
w1 = Canvas(frame2, width=600, height=300,background="white", scrollregion=(1500,1500,3000,3000))
scr_h1 = ttk.Scrollbar(frame2,orient=HORIZONTAL)
scr_h1.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
scr_h1.config(command=w1.xview)

scr_v1 = ttk.Scrollbar(frame2,orient=VERTICAL)
scr_v1.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
scr_v1.config(command=w1.yview)

w1.config(xscrollcommand=scr_h1.set,yscrollcommand=scr_v1.set)
w1.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)
```

Comment: There is not enough information in your question to give an answer. We need to see how you are creating the widget inside the canvas.

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me running Python 3.4 - a tkinter window pops up with a red oval (for testing), and the scrollbar allows you to navigate the frame.  If you are using Python 2, change `tkinter` to `Tkinter` (capital T).

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

frame2 = Frame(root)
frame2.pack(side=RIGHT)

w1 = Canvas(frame2, width=600, height=300,background="white", scrollregion=(0,0,3000,3000))


scr_h1 = Scrollbar(frame2,orient=HORIZONTAL)
scr_h1.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
scr_h1.config(command=w1.xview)

scr_v1 = Scrollbar(frame2,orient=VERTICAL)
scr_v1.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
scr_v1.config(command=w1.yview)

w1.config(xscrollcommand=scr_h1.set,yscrollcommand=scr_v1.set)
w1.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)

# inserted to see if it's actually scrolling
w1.create_oval(0,0,50,50,fill='red')


root.mainloop()
```

**Two Possible Issues**

1. Why were you using a ttk ScrollBar? The simple tkinter scroll bar will suffice for your code. When things aren't working, it might help to go back to the simpler model.
2. Why your starting scroll region was 1500 - any object placed on the canvas in the first 1500 units in either direction were not visible, with this setting, which may have given you the illusion that the scrollbar was not working. See http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-scrollbar-patterns.htm for more information on using scroll bars.

It should not matter that there are two frames or their orientation, though you may run into problems if you try to mix managers (grid,pack,etc.). These problems are more along the lines of stalled programs, not stationary scrollbars.