# Need help understanding/creating a scrollable frame with python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

I am somewhat new to python and totally new to user interfaces of this kind, so I apologize if I am not using the correct terminology.

I have also spent a good amount of time trying to create a solution or adapt an existing one and now my head is admittedly jumbled. I also recently posted this same question with a different iteration of making a scrolled area.

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(side=RIGHT)

w1 = Canvas(frame, width=600, height=300,scrollregion=(0,0,3000,3000))

scr_h1 = Scrollbar(orient=HORIZONTAL)
scr_h1.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill=X)
scr_h1.config(command=w1.xview)

scr_v1 = Scrollbar(orient=VERTICAL)
scr_v1.pack(side=RIGHT,fill=Y)
scr_v1.config(command=w1.yview)

w1.config(xscrollcommand=scr_h1.set,yscrollcommand=scr_v1.set)
w1.pack(fill=BOTH,expand=True)

#inserted to see if it's actually scrolling
w1.create_oval(0,0,50,50,fill='red')

data = information.read()

L1 = Label(root, text = 'A Title')
L1.pack(side=TOP)

text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, data)
text.pack()
```

This creates a canvas to the right of the original and scrolls the rightmost one (as tested with the red oval). How can I insert text portion on the same canvas as the scrollbar? I was told that anything added via pack (or grid or place) won't be able to scroll. What should I be doing instead?

The way the data is displayed now is just fine except for the fact that it exceeds the length of the screen so a scrollbar is required to view it. Right now, the data is dumped in its own individual canvas for each file, it's having a scrollbar for the entire set that would be helpful.

Thank you for taking the time and providing detailed feedback. Learning is a process and this function is something I'm having some issues utilizing.

This scrollbar framework taken from an answer here:
[tkinter: Can't make frame scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25132438/tkinter-cant-make-frame-scrollable/25695618#25695618)

Comment: Add a `Frame` into the `Canvas` which is scrollable !

Comment: @wolframalpha Please forgive my code fog, but I am having issues engineering that to happen.

Comment: Okay but what exactly you want to do ? Adding Frame to a canvas is as simple as `frame_in_canvas = Frame(w1)` you can then add anything into the `frame_in_canvas` and since w1 is the root of the Frame it will be scrollable. Your question is unclear!

Comment: @wolframalpha I'm sorry I'm not being clear enough. The code I have above will scroll but only for the "test" canvas I have to the right. I want only the data I'm dumping to be scrollable but as it is, it's just scrolling that right canvas. Adding in frame_in_canvas before my adding of my data doesn't change anything cause right now w1 and text aren't even "talking" to one another. I don't know how to add the text.pack() into w1.